# copy_if algorithm worth it here?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have the following method of some class, which also defines the method isAllowed:

```
auto filter(const auto& in)
{
    auto ret = decltype(in) {};
    for(auto x : in)
      if(isAllowed(x))
        ret.insert(x);
    return ret;
}
```

This is a clear case where copy_if could be used instead. I see two alternative versions:

```
auto filter(const auto& in)
{
    auto ret = decltype(in) {};
    copy_if(begin(in), end(in),
            inserter(ret, end(ret)), 
            [this](auto i) {return this->isAllowed(i);});
    return ret;
}
```

or

```
auto filter(const auto& in)
{
    auto ret = decltype(in) {};
    copy_if(begin(in), end(in),
            inserter(ret, end(ret)), 
            bind1st(mem_fn(&A::isAllowed), this)); // I believe this is deprecated
    return ret;
}
```

Both seem much less obvious than the original, so I am inclined to keep the for loop. Is there a strong argument not to? (And is there a better way?)

Otherwise, I feel itchy because cases like this point to the limited usefulness of the algorithm tools, despite what best practices advise.

Comment: I voted to close as primarily opinion based - there is no factual answer. You might have better luck at codereview.SE.

Comment: The final version is deprecated in favour of the more generic `bind(&A::isAllowed, this, _1)`. But stylistic "best practices" are highly opinionated, so this isn't really an answerable question. I'd use the loop, because it's clearer. Algorithms are sometimes clearer, but less often than they were without the new-style loop syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is a matter of opinion; but in *my* opinion, the algorithm-based one is clearer, because the name `copy_if` makes it clear what you're trying to accomplish.

You're (conditionally) copying a bunch of things.

Comment: +1 for the argument. I think many code readers would have to go figure what copy_if means first. On the other hand, it is harder to figure the source and target, as well as the filtering condition (in, ret, and isAllowed are obscured by more gibberish around them)